# Is it always necessary to restart streams after a Kafka broker outage/failover

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are using Kafka streams (0.11.0.1) api to consume events from topic. But whenever there is a Kafka Broker outage/failover, we need to restart all Kafka streamers to recover from following error:

"*Connection to node 39366 could not be established. Broker may not be available.*"

Just wondering if it is really required for streamers to do streams close and restart? Why streamers are not able recover from this issue automatically? Or are we missing any configuration in client/Broker?

Now we are planning to introduce code changes to handle all stream exception and trigger an automated restart of streams. But am really worried if that is the right way to handle this scenario.

If you think in a real world use case where hundreds of clients connected to brokers and restarting each of them, its not making any sense.

Comment: Maybe related to DNS caching in Java? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-jvm-ttl.html

Comment: Thanks Matt, I will try out this option and confirm.